# Required a bean of type Repository that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, repository, javabeans

I am setting up a new Spring project for some fun learning/tutorial at home and I seem to run into a fairly common issue but I have tried all possible solutions I found on here but with no luck. Basically what I have is as follows:

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/shop")
public class ShopController {

    @Autowired
    ShopService shopService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody Shop getTestData(@PathVariable String id) {
        return shopService.getShopBasedOnId(id);
    }

}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class ShopService {

    @Autowired
    private ShopRepository shopRepository;

    public ShopService(ShopRepository shopRepository){
        this.shopRepository = shopRepository;
    }

    public Shop getShopBasedOnId(String id) {
        return shopRepository.findByShopId(id);
    }
}
```

Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface ShopRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Shop, String> {

        Shop findByShopId(String shopId);
}
```

Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.reservations.repository")
public class ReservationsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReservationsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Last but not least my pom.xml with the dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

So the error code I am getting is as follows:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.reservations.services.ShopService required a bean of type 'com.example.reservations.repository.ShopRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.reservations.repository.ShopRepository' in your configuration.
```

My structure of folders is:

```
main
 |_java
    |_com.example.reservations
         |_controllers
              |_ShopController.java
         |_repository
              |_ShopRepository.java
         |_services
              |_ShopService.java
         |_ReservationsApplication.java
```

Comment: Did you try annotating `ShopService` with `@Component` so Spring can find it when it does component scanning?

Comment: I have ```@Service``` annotation on ShopService, isnt like @Component included into that?

Comment: I see you updated the source code. Yes, `@Service` should be sufficient.

Comment: what is the data type of Shop entity  primary key , is it a String

Comment: Remove  @Autowired on the field in ShopService , you are using both field injection and constructor injection.

Comment: Can you share the "caused by"? the bottom of the stacktrace...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to have a config file for couchbase repository. What I did was follow the following [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-couchbase) and now it all compiles fine!

Answer (score 0):

The problem  could be @Autowired in ShopService

```
@Service

public class ShopService {

@Autowired
private ShopRepository shopRepository;

public ShopService(ShopRepository shopRepository){
    this.shopRepository = shopRepository;
}

public Shop getShopBasedOnId(String id) {
    return shopRepository.findByShopId(id);
}
 }`
```

should be
@Service
public class ShopService {

```
private ShopRepository shopRepository;

public ShopService(ShopRepository shopRepository){
    this.shopRepository = shopRepository;
}

public Shop getShopBasedOnId(String id) {
    return shopRepository.findByShopId(id);
}
}
```

You can also add `@Autowired` just above the constructor but it is no longer required if there is only one constructor

Comment: I tried removing the ```@Autowired``` above ShopRepository but didnt work.
Also I do have ```@Service``` annotation above ShopService.
```ShopRepository``` is an interface Repository and so I cant define a constructor plus I have ```@Repository``` annotation

Comment: I have a feeling that there is an issue with my pom file and im missing some dependency

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I had spring boot with multiple modules. So I had to the below to make it work.

```
@SpringBootApplication (scanBasePackages={"com.sample.test"})
@EnableJdbcRepositories(basePackages={"com.sample.test"})
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```